# Align div to bottom in Bootstrap Row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can i align `div` with class `heightSmall` to bottom of `row`? I try with `vertical-align: bottom` but this doesn't help.

```css
.heightBig{height:100px;background-color:red;}
.heightSmall{height:50px;background-color:green;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="heightBig"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="heightSmall"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kmandov mentioned use the table-structure display to get what you are looking for and use media queries to change the display style for small screen. Example **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/cgmcd8en/)**

CSS would look like this

```
@media (min-width: 768px){ /*for bigger screens*/
   .row{
        display:table-row;
   }    
   .col-sm-6{
        display:table-cell;
        float: none;
   }
}

@media (max-width: 768px){/*for smaller screens*/
    .col-sm-6{
        float:left;
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

See if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This may be done by changing the display type to table and table-row

Here is a similar solution:
http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-columns-of-same-height

Comment: thanks for reply. But this is not solution for small sizes of screen. I want that .heightSmall become under .heightBig for small screens. With your suggestion it's imposible i think

Comment: Could you fix link and even better - provide solution (summary) in your answer